# Problem on Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Question-

$X_n$ can take only two values $n^a$ and $-n^a$ with equal probabilities. Show that we can apply weak law of large numbers to the sequence of independent random vatiables ${X_n}$ if $a<\frac{1}{2}$.

We have to show that$Var(\overline{X_n})$ $\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. I can show that if $a>1/2$ then $Var(\overline{X_n})$  does not tend to $0$ but i can not prove that wlln can be applied if $a<1/2$.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $Var(\bar{X_n})$ does not tend to 1/2 for $a> 1/2$.

Comment: Sorry i meant it is greater than $1/2$

Comment: OK.  I have a hard time seeing how an argument for $a>1/2$ doesn't immediately lead to the corresponding argument for $a<1/2$.  Can you sketch out your argument for $a>1/2$?

Comment: Well if a>1/2 then $ var(\overline{X}_n)=\frac{1+2^a+...+n^a}{n^2}$ which is greater than $\frac{1+2+...+n}{n^2}$ which tends to $1/2$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: I think you want $2a$ in those exponents instead of $a$, but basically yes.  I guess you weren't sure how to sum the numerator in general.  saz below provides a solution by just bounding each term by $n^{2a}$ which certainly works.  Do you know about the integral test?  It isn't hard to show that $1+2^{2a}+...+n^{2a}$ grows asymptotically as $n^{2a+1}/(2a+1)$.  Then plugging in $a<1/2$ shows you that  the expression is $o(n^2)$.

Comment: Sorry but how  to apply integral test here?

Comment: You compare $1+2^{2a}+...+n^{2a}$ to $\int_1^n x^{2a}dx$

Comment: Thanks! Now i get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide us with any details on your calculations, it is hard to say where you went wrong.

Since the random variables $X_n$, $n \geq 1$, are independent and have mean $0$, it holds for $\bar{X}_n := n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ that

$$\text{var}(\bar{X}_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \text{var}(X_i) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_i^2).$$

By assumption,

$$\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = \frac{1}{2} (i^a)^2 +\frac{1}{2} (-i^a)^2 = i^{2a},$$

and so

$$\text{var}(\bar{X}_n)= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n i^{2a}.$$

Since $i^{2a} \leq n^{2a}$ for any $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$  this implies

$$\text{var}(\bar{X}_n)\leq \frac{n^{2a}}{n} \xrightarrow[2a<1]{n \to \infty} 0.$$

Applying Markov's inequality (/Tschebysheff inequality) it follows that the weak law of large numbers holds.

Comment: I don't think that last step is quite right.  The bound isn't $1/n$.  For instance, if $a=1/2$, the variance tends to 1/2.

Comment: @norfair Sorry, was a bit too rough; should be fine now.